# I wish to write data into existing textboxes on powerpoint using VBA, but none of the codes work

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am stuck writing a code to paste data from certain cells into Powerpoint.

The code currently makes my Macbook crash when running.

To read the data I am using the following code:

```
Dim ppSlide As Object 'PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape As Object 'PowerPoint.Shape

Sub getshapedata2()
On Error GoTo line1
    Dim ppSlide As Object 'PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppShape As Object 'PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim nextrow As Long

    Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
    Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
    Set ppSlide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    For Each ppShape In GetPPTSelection(pppres.Windows(1))
        friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & 
shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")
        With Sheet1
            nextrow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("a" & nextrow) = ppSlide.SlideIndex
            .Range("b" & nextrow) = ppShape.Name
            .Range("c" & nextrow) = ppShape.TextEffect.Text
            .Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname
        End With
    Next

Exit Sub

line1:
MsgBox "no item selected"

End Sub

Function GetPPTSelection(window As Object)

' Returns a Collection of selected shapes, if shapes are selected
' Returns a Nothing, if anything else (slides, text, etc.) selected
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim c As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim g As Integer

Dim sel As Object '# PowerPoint.Selection

Const ppSelectionShapes As Long = 2  ' in case of late binding

Set sel = window.Selection

If sel.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
    For s = 1 To sel.ShapeRange.Count
        If IsGrouped(sel.ShapeRange(s)) Then
            '# handle grouped shapes
            For g = 1 To sel.ShapeRange(s).GroupItems.Count
            coll.Add sel.ShapeRange(s).GroupItems(g)
            Next
        Else:
            '# ordinary, ungrouped shapes:
            coll.Add sel.ShapeRange(s)
        End If
    Next
End If

'# Get rid of any shapes which don't have a textframe:
For c = coll.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Not coll(c).HasTextFrame Then coll.Remove (c)
Next

'# Return the collection to the calling procedure:
Set GetPPTSelection = coll

End Function

Function IsGrouped(shp As Object)
'Returns boolean if shape is groupshapes
Dim ret As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
ret = shp.GroupItems.Count > 1
IsGrouped = ret

End Function
```

To then repaste the value in the selected textboxes I am using the following code:

```
Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub writedata()

Dim c As Object
Dim shapeslide As Integer
Dim shapename As Integer
Dim shapetext As Integer


Set ppapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row)


shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = Sheet1.Range("c" & c.Row)
friendlyname = Sheet1.Range("d" & c.Row)

ppapp.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = 
shapetext

Next c

End Sub
```

As mentioned earlier my macbook Excel is crashing when running the second code while the first one works perfect (probably due to the .Text).

I have tried many variations already, however I keep being stuck. Hope someone might be able to help me solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it crash?  It could be trying to bounce back and forth between applications.  Do you have multiple workbooks open?

Comment: hi Liss, to my knowledge it is a bug in Mac Excel with reading not well defined .Text functions... I have tried to close everything, but it is not working sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual way to add text to a shape:

```
ppapp.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext
```

Normally you'd do:

```
ppapp.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shapetext
```

I'd also try declaring your functions properly:

Change

```
Function GetPPTSelection(window As Object)
```

To

```
Function GetPPTSelection(window As Object) As Collection
```

You're letting VBA guess what the function's supposed to return instead of telling it. Sometimes VBA gets it right, sometimes not and when not, the bugs can be very difficult to track down.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Now, however it gives me the error message "Method or data member not found" (highlighting .Slides in the ppapp.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shapetext function)

Comment: Sorry, that should be pppres.Slides instead of ppapp.slides.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks again! Now however it gives a Type Mismatch error... When clicking debug the excel sheet shuts down. Could this be a bug in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Also , when I Define the Shapename etc. as any other variable than Integer the program shuts down without any warning. Could this be a bug in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: I'd post the code as it currently stands.  Indicate what errors occur and *where* they occur.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , Above you can find the code as it stands, however, it only crashes, not saying where the error takes place...

Comment: Add a break point early in the code then step through it line by line in the VB editor to find out what line causes the problem. AH, and instead of using For Each [] in Whatever loops, use For X = 1 to Whatever.Count ... Mac PPT is buggy as sin, and in some cases, For Each oSh in xxx.Shapes will trigger an immediate crash, no error message, the PPT app just disappears.

Comment: Thanks so much for your tips! However I don't really understand how to modify the "For Each" sequence. Should I change it to "For c=1 to Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Count" ? My apologies for the basic question. Thanks again for all the help,!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Private Sub writedata()

On Error GoTo Whoa

Dim c As Object
Dim shapeslide As Integer
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext


Set ppapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)


shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = Sheet1.Range("c" & c.Row)
friendlyname = Sheet1.Range("d" & c.Row)


pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextFrame.TextRange.Text 
= shapetext


Next c
Exit Sub

Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

The Error is not described , the message is Excel has shut down unexcpected. This is the main issue.

Thanks again.